# SVGZ (compressed SVG) does not work with ePub readers

Tags: svg, epub, svgz

I was trying to embed compressed SVG file (.SVGZ) to xhtml file of epub like this

```
<embed class="imageobject" name="297129.sch.001" src="images/out-svgz/297129.sch.001.svgz"/>
```

,when i tested it on various readers,the result was blank space instead of the figures,i know it is a problem of "Content-encoding" which configured on web servers in case of web apps,how can i do the same on my ePub ?

Comment: svgz is about content-encoding, not content-type

Comment: you are right, already edited the question.